# SSAS Grand Total for calculated measure in excel not working

Tags: sql, excel, ssas, mdx

I have an ssas cube with a calculated member called cumulative ptp's.
Everything seems to work in excel except for the Grand Total which is displaying #Value!. I'm not sure where the problem is. I've added a few pics of what I have done. Any help will be most appreciated. Thanks in advance.
[image: Calculated Member]
[image: Excel Results]

```
IIF
(
[Day-Month Analysis].[Day].FIRSTCHILD = [Day-Month Analysis]. [Day].CURRENTMEMBER,

 Sum(
{[Day-Month Analysis].[Day].FIRSTCHILD:[Day-Month Analysis].  [Day].CURRENTMEMBER},
[Measures].[Sum of IsPTP]
)
,  SUM(Measures.[Sum of IsPTP])
)
```

So I downloaded that extension and the MDX error is:
"Range operator (:) operands' have different levels; they must be the same"

Comment: Can you install OLAP PivotTable Extensions and run this feature to get an error message for the #VALUE! cell? http://olappivottableextend.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View%20Error%20Message&referringTitle=Home

Comment: Pasting your MDX into this thread will save someone time retyping it from the image. Please do this.

Comment: Hi Greg I have added the code. I am also looking into that link that you shared. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sum(
{[Null:[Day-Month Analysis].[Day].CURRENTMEMBER},
[Measures].[Sum of IsPTP]
)
```

I don't think you need the IIf. If that doesn't work right describe what's in that [Day] hierarchy further.

Comment: @LiamDomingo by the way your code had iif(a=b but you probably wanted iif(a is b. The equals sign evaluates a measure value. But "is" compares member references. I didn't totally understand what you were accomplishing with IIf and you didn't need it but be careful with that in the future.